# How to extract year, month and date from a ngbDatepicker to send over httpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to select a date with a ngbDatepicker to then send the year, month and date value over httpClient to my backend to filter a Page of Entities, called "Show, according to that date. The backend takes the Integers "year", "month" and "day" as parameters.

My current problem is:

If I have no date selected, I correctly get all Elements, but if I select any Date in the datepicker I always get an empty list. If I hardcode the year, month and day, regardless of what was picked, in the httpClient params, I get the correctly filtered list, so I figured there's a problem how I process the Date from the datepicker.

My datepicker implementation in my .html-file:

```html
<!-- other code -->
<form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                   name="dp" ref-selectedDate ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" id="picker">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
<!-- other code -->
<button (click)="search(selectedDate.value)" type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Suchen </button>
<!-- other code -->
```

the search function in my .ts-file:

```js
// other code
private search(selectedDate: Date) {
    this.shows = [];
    this.eventService.getShowPage(this.event.id, selectedDate, this.page, this.pageSize).subscribe(
      (page: Page<Show>) => {
        this.processShowResponse(page.content);
        this.shows = page.content;
        this.totalItems = page.totalElements;
      },
      error => {
        this.defaultServiceErrorHandling(error);
      }
    );
  }
// other code
```

And my service-class:

```js
// other code
getShowPage(eventId: number, searchDate: Date, page: number = 1, size: number = 25): Observable<Page<Show>> {
    this.log('Load shows of event with id ' + eventId + ' on page ' + page);
    let params = new HttpParams().set('page', (page - 1).toString()).set('size', size.toString());
    const url = this.eventBaseUri + '/' + eventId + this.showsUri;

    if (searchDate) {
      params = params.set('year', searchDate.getFullYear().toString());
      params = params.set('month', searchDate.getMonth().toString());
      params = params.set('day',  searchDate.getDate().toString());
    }
    return this.httpClient.get<Page<Show>>(url, {params: params})
      .pipe(map(resp => {
        resp.number++;
        return resp;
      }));
  }
// other code
```

Comment: When you say you get an empty list, is the response coming as empty or `searchDate` is empty?

Comment: I solved my problem and posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was that the value from the datepicker had the format "yyyy-mm-dd", which couldn't be automatically casted to Date.

I fixed it by adding:

```js
const splitDate = selectedDate.split('-');
year = Number(splitDate[0]);
month = Number(splitDate[1]);
day = Number(splitDate[2]);
searchDate = new Date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

to the component.ts